# How to use user's access token or access token based on Tenant ID in Microsoft graph API?

Tags: php, laravel, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-entra-id

[image]
[image]
Here are the methods I tried using the Microsoft Graph API and their respective outcomes:

Method 1:

- After Single Sign-On (SSO), we obtain an access token.
- This access token is used as a bearer token for Graph API integration.

```php
    public function redirectToMicrosoft(){
        return Socialize::driver('graph')->scopes(['offline_access'])->redirect();
        }

    public function handleMicrosoftCallback(){   
        $user = Socialize::driver('graph')->user();
        return $user->access_token;
    }
```

- Resulted in the following error:

  - URL: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/onenote/pages
  - Response:

    - Error Code: 40001
    - Error Message: "The request does not contain a valid authentication token."
  - URL: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/gowrishankari97@outlook.com/events
  - Response:

    - Error Code: ErrorAccessDenied
    - Error Message: "Access is denied. Check credentials and try again."

Method 2:

- Obtaining an access token based on the tenant ID and specified parameters.
- Using the obtained access token.

```php
    public function getAccessToken()
    {
        $tenantId = env('MICROSOFT_TENANT_ID');
        $clientSecret = env('MICROSOFT_CLIENT_SECRET');
        $clientId = env('MICROSOFT_CLIENT_ID');        
    
        $input = [
            'grant_type' => 'client_credentials',
            'client_id' => $clientId,
            'scope' =>"https://graph.microsoft.com/.default",
            'client_secret' => $clientSecret,
        ];
      
        $client = new Client();
        $response = $client->request('POST', "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$tenantId/oauth2/v2.0/token", ['form_params' => $input]);
     
        $statusCode = $response->getStatusCode();
        $responseBody = json_decode($response->getBody(), true);
    
        $this->accessToken = $responseBody['access_token'];
        return $responseBody;
    }
```

- Resulted in the following errors:

  - URL: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events

    - Response:

      - Error Code: BadRequest
      - Error Message: "/me request is only valid with delegated authentication flow."
  - URL: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/gowrishankari97@outlook.com/events

    - Response:

      - Error Code: OrganizationFromTenantGuidNotFound
      - Error Message: "The tenant for tenant guid '{TENANT_ID}' does not exist."

UPDATE:

Kindly find the permission below,
[image]

When attempting to sign in with an Azure AD-configured email, which involves registering an email address to obtain a client and secret. I get the code and the access token API works fine.

[image]

When attempting to sign in with different outlook mail, I get the below error. Please refer the screenshot,

[image]

**CODE**
0.AS4AgI6YLYeIu0eXbgo3fHk6PszspcPofddJs-W7b5ajEO-5AC8.AgABAAIAAAAmoFfGtYxvRrNriQdPKIZ-AgDs_wUA9P-kBJSNPkGJJsNJgB510cZ69mO3JTSYLh89i4PpBhv1Y8L0nk51BFcTUh7bEe2i5dC24W1eeEqsOCuGKJcUYbmfdHCKHkpnaUBAFoHsIGhyydpHwMvezF4pAnL8_-OxgJeM-xPaj3WFxqZfEvwP6R4TFxQ4IP5hovS1erTxlMCS63dA9hdL7jbkpDHjrp3wgqs01zRt_q5RAPCH4KtRGtirnMnll-3PSEkcLixKUQkeC261Z_0JsK5aGRidAv0IFNs_nw5cPtowTEuEiv99EJZQLJbt7qLOhz0DIPBBeBhpJl2bi6OsdOV4UZ59eQafOEanxA-5_pC6gy3H3nc9kiVfPddlneBXKGbFbaoXHyl9hi_i7bzNcJDubNteM2TQETYy7VgnoRpNEbh_eOZNV4T1rVtr8h5F4fxg9MaWkmQog8s9dxtDwY4MCYq9UBb1tVTeOlm38w3oyQWR-3ZCbD8wV4IZV3TEzrqJfhURm8E_cgcgTLdzOm-8uK9f-E0NAC4aodqXf_V3d8wLtR6QJi-WNOKlB-8THR-WNuMZvBcZiL38h_zToPbgwnL0fSRfsuoU57kwE8t30HpcDzRq2PilxgdDjoGolStRNEv-RDrgTS-66EewjHevBwbU_5A0nSfNzjhksl5NQfuEdnoRSZ3QTH4jwLgzIZ3aSkwphkoRtDJRa_Ri1U8PdAzolRl2SlJIYp7sqvIfpPL9SSRgEA6ftusb8seE9gEcGXKvvRFEQza4KgrsC9NHNMQunJFlQxbb5Y1SpdgRWC9BsK7oIGgegj5F4CKoBgKqlaOmis2I_QvZxVil5KSq4zft&state=12345&session_state=9c29347d-1351-48c8-90dc-c1ab380a6221

Comment: Could you include what `API permissions` you granted in your application by editing your question with screenshot from Portal?

Comment: I don't know much about this, but I think it would be better to choose a method and then show the actual code you used. Questions with [real code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in them, that [reproduce the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), often get better responses. Asking a proper question can also help.

Comment: Please find the permission screenshot attached. And also, I have attached the code for reference.

Comment: Could you confirm whether the user has an active Office 365 license assigned or not?

Comment: I have an outlook login. Do we need to purchase any license on the same?

Comment: Yes, you need to purchase Office 365 license for creating events in outlook calendars. Refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1289831/error-organizationfromtenantguidnotfound-(even-wit))

Comment: Yes, that worked, I'm sorry, I cannot help you with this problem. I always try to stay as far away from big tech like Amazon, Google and Microsoft, as possible. Not always succeeding, of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Note that, you **cannot** fetch personal Outlook calendar events using token generated with **client credentials** flow.
>
> You need to switch to **delegated** flows like authorization code flow by granting delegated permissions with **`/common`** endpoint.

In my case, I registered one **multi-tenant** application with below **account type** that allows both organizational and personal Microsoft accounts:

[image]

Now, I granted **`Calendars.ReadWrite`** permission of **Delegated** type in that application as below:

[image]

Initially, I ran below **authorization request** in browser that displayed consent screen after signing in:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize? 
client_id=appId
&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms
&response_type=code  
&response_mode=query  
&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
&state=12345
```

[image]

After accepting the consent, I got authorization **`code`** value in address bar:

[image]

Now, I generated **access token** using authorization code flow via Postman with below parameters including  **`code`** value:

```http
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantId/oauth2/v2.0/token
grant_type: authorization_code
client_id: appId 
client_secret: secret 
scope: https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
code: paste_code_from_above
redirect_uri: https://jwt.ms
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I used this token to fetch events of personal outlook calendar user, I got the **response** successfully as below:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events
```

**Response:**

[image]

If you are trying to list or create events in normal Azure AD user account, make sure to assign an active **Office 365 license** to the user.

**UPDATE:**

Note that, the error `Invalid request. Request is malformed or invalid` usually occurs if you are passing **invalid** values in token parameters.

I got the **same error** when passed **invalid** or **extra** characters in **`code`** parameter while generating token like this:

[image]

To resolve the error, you should remove this part `&state=12345&session_state=9c29347d-1351-48c8-90dc-c1ab380a6221` from `code` parameter

Your valid **`code`** value should be this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the brief explanation. In my app, multiple users need specific access tokens for calendars, OneNote etc. I encountered an error when trying to obtain an access token for individual users; it says "Invalid request. Request is malformed or invalid". Access token API works fine for Azure AD-registered emails. How can I handle other users?

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by individual users and how you are getting token for them?

Comment: Good explanation @Sridevi

Comment: @Sridevi I have mentioned the explanation in question section with adding **UPDATE** text. Please check the same.

Comment: I noticed that your `code` value is different for other outlook account user.  Could you please paste how you got code for that other user?

Comment: I have updated in question section as the code exceeds the character in which comment can't be added. Added the text **CODE** to identify

Comment: I mean using an organization email, I get this code.

Comment: Please check the updated answer. You need to remove `&state=12345&session_state=9c29347d-1351-48c8-90dc-c1ab380a6221` from **code** parameter.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255864/discussion-between-sridevi-and-shankari).