# Graph API - Read calendar of invited users

Tags: azure, outlook, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-entra-id

My SaaS app needs to gather information from Outlook calendars.
I created an app registration in Azure Entra and invited a couple people.

The required calendar Application permissions are set up under the API permissions tab.

I keep getting the error "The mailbox is either inactive, soft-deleted, or is hosted on-premise."

It seems that this is because the users I'm inviting were not created by me, under my tenant.  Is there any way for me to make this work?  I'm wondering how other software like
Calendly get access to their users' calendars?

Comment: You cannot read calendar of invited users using _Application_ permissions. You need to grant permissions of _Delegated_ type and use **delegated** flows like interactive flow or authorization code flow in getting token using `/common` endpoint by registering application with account type as _Accounts in any organizational directory (Any Microsoft Entra ID tenant - Multitenant) and personal Microsoft accounts (e.g. Skype, Xbox)_ to read personal Outlook calendars.

Comment: @Sridevi Is that something you need the user to initiate each time? So a polling server that looks for calendar changes every 10 minutes isn't possible?

Comment: Yes, user need to login every time while using delegated flows. Refer this to fetch personal Outlook calendar events with delegated flow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77431323/how-to-use-users-access-token-or-access-token-based-on-tenant-id-in-microsoft-g/77437176#77437176