# try to get authorization_code with person account but get AADSTS9002313 error

Tags: java, azure, azure-active-directory

I've created an authentication app in Azure to allow access for all users. However, I can only access it using accounts within my organization; accounts outside of the organization(xbox live account or others) fail to obtain the authentication code and encounter the error

"**`{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"AADSTS9002313: Invalid request. Request is malformed or invalid. Trace ID: 7473f2b4-1e1b-4428-8e44-dbb5a6aab900 Correlation ID: 4930db75-6422-41d2-84f4-7ed4655881e9 Timestamp: 2024-03-26 09:10:29Z","error_codes":[9002313],"timestamp":"2024-03-26 09:10:29Z","trace_id":"7473f2b4-1e1b-4428-8e44-dbb5a6aab900","correlation_id":"4930db75-6422-41d2-84f4-7ed4655881e9","error_uri":"https://login.microsoftonline.com/error?code=9002313"}"`**

when l got the redirect url is **http://localhost:8080/api/admin/office365_calendar/refresh_token?code=M.C549_BAY.2.U.49655a0d-92d0-9af4-a8ca-168d922a125e&state=71074f34-96f0-4ad3-84b4-69c35c9b208a**
which code is obviously strange....

here is my endpoint: https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?

My settings should be correct, as shown in the screenshot below:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQ0pm.png]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9PFM.png]

ls there somebody can tell me how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **personal** Microsoft accounts *(Outlook, Gmail)* to login, your `code` value will start with *M.C* which is default behavior.

I registered one multi-tenant application and granted `API permissions` as below:

[image]

In my case, I used https://jwt.ms as **redirect URI** in my app registration:

[image]

When I ran below authorize URL and signed in with **personal** Microsoft account, I too got `code` value starts with *M.C* :

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize? 
client_id=appID
&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms
&response_type=code
&prompt=select_account    
&scope=openid offline_access Calendars.ReadWrite User.Read
&state=12345
```

[image]

Now, I used this `code` to generate access token via Postman with below parameters and got **response** like this:

```http
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token
grant_type: authorization_code
client_id: appId 
client_secret: secret 
scope: https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
code: paste_code_from_above
redirect_uri: https://jwt.ms
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I used this token to fetch user's calendar events, I got **response** successfully like this:

```http
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events
```

**Response:**

[image]

**Reference:**
[php - How to use user's access token or access token based on Tenant ID in Microsoft graph API? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77431323/how-to-use-users-access-token-or-access-token-based-on-tenant-id-in-microsoft-g/77437176#77437176)

Comment: l made a stupid mistake... the endpoint url should be https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token, and l used https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token, that's the reason