How to get authorizationCode in MS Graph API 6.12
I'm using microsoft-graph:6.12.0 in my Android Java App.
I'm struggling for searching files on onedrive.
How can I get authorizsationCode for AuthorizationCodeCredentialBuilder.
final AuthorizationCodeCredential credential = new AuthorizationCodeCredentialBuilder()
                .clientId(CLIENT_ID).tenantId(TENANT_ID).clientSecret(CLIENT_SECRET_VALUE)
                .authorizationCode(authorizationCode).redirectUrl(REDIRECT_URL).build();

Thanks
GGK

To get authorization code, you need to run authorization request in browser that gives code in address bar after signing in. Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77431323/how-to-use-users-access-token-or-access-token-based-on-tenant-id-in-microsoft-g/77437176#77437176

Initially, register one Entra ID application with redirect URI as below:

Make sure to grant Files.Read permission of Delegated type in this application:

To get authorization code, you need to run below request in browser that asks user to login like this:
https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantId/oauth2/v2.0/authorize? 
client_id=appId
&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms
&response_type=code  
&response_mode=query  
&scope=Files.Read
&state=12345


After successful authentication, you will get authorization code in the address bar like this:

In my case, I used below sample java code to get user's drive by including authorizationCode value like this:
Main.java:
import com.azure.identity.AuthorizationCodeCredential;
import com.azure.identity.AuthorizationCodeCredentialBuilder;
import com.microsoft.graph.models.Drive;
import com.microsoft.graph.serviceclient.GraphServiceClient;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String clientId = "appId";
        final String tenantId = "tenantId"; 
        final String clientSecret = "secret";
        final String authorizationCode = "code_value";
        final String redirectUrl = "https://jwt.ms";
        final String[] scopes = new String[] { "Files.Read" };

        final AuthorizationCodeCredential credential = new AuthorizationCodeCredentialBuilder()
                .clientId(clientId).tenantId(tenantId).clientSecret(clientSecret)
                .authorizationCode(authorizationCode).redirectUrl(redirectUrl).build();

        final GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(credential, scopes);
        Drive response = graphClient.me().drive().get();
        System.out.println("Drive ID: "+ response.getId());
    }
}

Response:

Reference:
Choose a Microsoft Graph authentication provider - Microsoft Graph 
